# Getting error page while running the servlet

Tags: jakarta-ee

I have created a dynamic web Project in eclipse Juno and while running on server (Tomcat6.0), getting the error page HTTP Status 404 - /FirstServlet/ with below  message :

> type Status report
>
> message /FirstServlet/
>
> description The requested resource (/FirstServlet/) is not available.

Here I observe the url is was ---http://localhost:5533/FirstServlet/

Can any one tell me how to resolve it.

Here are the files created in FirstServlet

**Servlet class code**

```
package com.surendra.servlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class HelloWorldServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
       
    
    public HelloWorldServlet() {
        super();
    }
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter p = response.getWriter();
        p.println("Hello World");
    }
        
}
```

**Web.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
      <display-name>FirstServlet</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>first</display-name>
    <servlet-name>HelloWorldServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.surendra.servlets.HelloWorldServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>first</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/HelloWorldServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your web.xml to:

```
<servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>first</display-name>
    <servlet-name>FirstServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.surendra.servlets.HelloWorldServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FirstServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/FirstServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

In your web.xml, the URL pattern describes the URL you're going to use:

```
<url-pattern>/XXXX</url-pattern> --> http://localhost:5533/XXXX/
```

Also the `servlet-name` must match the servlet description

```
<servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>first</display-name>
    <servlet-name>XXXXXXXXXX</servlet-name>  <!--- HERE ---->
    <servlet-class>com.surendra.servlets.HelloWorldServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>XXXXXXXXXX</servlet-name>  <!--- AND HERE ---->
    <url-pattern>/FirstServlet</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Also, the webapp's context path must be prepended: `http://localhost:5533/theWebApp/XXXX`

Comment: I updated my web.xml as you have mentioned,but still I am getting the same error ,

Answer (score 0):

Also you should access it as /HelloWorldServlet  or follow the previous authors configuration to access it as /FirstServlet as mentioned in the URL pattern.

Some minor things to additionally check. What is your war file name? Have you copied/deployed into your application server folder?

If so your url should be `http://localhost:8080/war_name/servlet_name`.